# Issue encountered with the history parameter in the Gemini AI integration within a Node.js environment

Tags: node.js, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, google-gemini, gemini

I copied and pasted the Gemini document directly into my Node.js server, and I encountered an error related to the `history` parameter.

```
{"error": "Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'text' in H"}
```

However, the operation succeeded when I set `history` to `null`.

this is my code :

```
   history: [
  {
    role: "user",
    parts: : "Hello, I have 2 dogs in my house.",
  },
  {
    role: "model",
    parts: "Great to meet you. What would you like to know?",
  },
],
generationConfig: {
  maxOutputTokens: 100,
},
```

});

and this is the error i got in the console :

```
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'text' in H
    at validateChatHistory (C:\myprojects\chat_app_generativeai_dartfrog\server\node_modules\@google\generative-ai\dist\index.js:760:25)
    at new ChatSession (C:\myprojects\chat_app_generativeai_dartfrog\server\node_modules\@google\generative-ai\dist\index.js:816:13)
    at GenerativeModel.startChat (C:\myprojects\chat_app_generativeai_dartfrog\server\node_modules\@google\generative-ai\dist\index.js:1035:16)
    at C:\myprojects\chat_app_generativeai_dartfrog\server\routes\chat.js:21:22
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\myprojects\chat_app_generativeai_dartfrog\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\myprojects\chat_app_generativeai_dartfrog\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:149:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\myprojects\chat_app_generativeai_dartfrog\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:119:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\myprojects\chat_app_generativeai_dartfrog\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\myprojects\chat_app_generativeai_dartfrog\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (C:\myprojects\chat_app_generativeai_dartfrog\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
```

Comment: Please do **not** post images of code - see how to create a [mre].

Comment: I encountered an issue with a Google document and resolved it. then you give me negative point , what is wrong with you guys in stack overflow , u could suggest me to remove image and use code , try to not hate everything and every one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current structure of the chat history in Google document does not accurately reflect the expected format for multi-turn conversations. The model appears to be incorrectly handling the conversation turns, leading to errors in the conversation flow.
To fix this issue, I propose the following enhancement to the chat history model:

```
   const chatHistory = [
 {
    role: "user",
    parts: [{
      text: "Hello, I have 2 dogs in my house." 
    }]
 },
 {
    role: "model",
    parts: [{
      text: "Great to meet you." 
    }]
 }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there was an issue with the latest version in this issue: https://github.com/google/generative-ai-js/pull/32

try using an older version of gemini.
I've installed '@google/generative-ai@0.2.1' and it solved the problem for me

Comment: thank you aviv , this problem is from their Document and i find the solution , also send  them a feedback to fix the problem